# onClick MediaPlayer error all audios are played

Tags: java, android-studio, onclick, android-mediaplayer, cardview

When i click a cardviewer to play a sound, all audios play at the same time, and i just want to click one cardviewer and correspond with that audio

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    final MediaPlayer sonidoGato = MediaPlayer.create(Juego3Activity.this, R.raw.gato);
    final MediaPlayer sonidoPerro = MediaPlayer.create(Juego3Activity.this, R.raw.perro);
    final MediaPlayer sonidoPez = MediaPlayer.create(Juego3Activity.this, R.raw.pez);
    final MediaPlayer sonidoPanda = MediaPlayer.create(Juego3Activity.this, R.raw.panda);
    final MediaPlayer sonidoConejo = MediaPlayer.create(Juego3Activity.this, R.raw.conejo);
    final MediaPlayer sonidoHamster = MediaPlayer.create(Juego3Activity.this, R.raw.hamster);

    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.cardGato : sonidoGato.start() ;
        case R.id.cardPerro : sonidoPerro.start();
        case R.id.cardPez : sonidoPez.start();
        case R.id.cardPanda : sonidoPanda.start();
        case R.id.cardConejo : sonidoConejo.start();
        case R.id.cardHamster : sonidoHamster.start();
    }
```

Comment: you need a `break;` in your cases...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little help on how to use 
[Switch statement:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

You forgot to use "break;" on each "case".

```
switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.cardGato : sonidoGato.start() ;
                         break;
    case R.id.cardPerro : sonidoPerro.start();
                          break;
    case R.id.cardPez : sonidoPez.start();
                        break;
    case R.id.cardPanda : sonidoPanda.start();
                         break;
    case R.id.cardConejo : sonidoConejo.start();
                           break;
    case R.id.cardHamster : sonidoHamster.start();
                            break;
}
```